# Unable to determine SQL type for... when creating tables with LinQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I got the following code:

```
public class SqlData : DataContext
{
    public Table<TextbausteinTyp> TextbausteinTypen;
    public SqlData(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)    {      }

    public void CreateDb()
    {
       CreateDatabase();
    }
}
[Table(Name = "tqTextbausteinTyp")]
public class TextbausteinTyp
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, DbType = "BigInt IDENTITY NOT NULL", IsDbGenerated = true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public int Id;
    [Column]
    public string Name;
}

[Table(Name = "tqTextbaustein")]
public class Textbaustein
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, DbType = "BigInt IDENTITY NOT NULL", IsDbGenerated = true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public int Id;
    [Column]
    public TextbausteinTyp IdBausteintyp;
    [Column]
    public string Inhalt;
    [Column]
    public string Name;
}
```

As you can see, it is quite simple. When executing CreateDatabase() I receive the following error:

> Unable to determine SQL type for 'tqOrder.data.TextbausteinTyp'

The Connection string leads to a MSSQL-Database which is created by this code (but without the table)

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Isn't `DbType` an enumeration? I guess you cant assign a string value to that. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.dbtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: according to msdn it isnt: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.dbtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What version of MSSQL Server are you using?

Comment: I was on the complete wrong path :) It wasn't the "TextbausteinTyp"-Class that caused the error, but a reference to that Table/Class in another class/table that was wrong. I will update my question, so the real wrong part is revealed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unable to determine SQL type for 'tqOrder.data.TextbausteinTyp'

I'm not surprised, as I can't determine the SQL type for it either. How is a table meant to be a column in another table?

I imagine, but cannot be sure, that you actually want something like:

```
[Column(CanBeNull=false,DbType="int not null")]
public int IdBausteintyp;
```

So as to have a foreign-key column that references the `IdBausteintyp` column (I'd prefer to end with "id" rather than begin with it, but that's another matter).

You can from that starting point then add:

```
private EntityRef<TextbausteinTyp> _textbausteinTyp;
[Association(Storage = "_textbausteinTyp", ThisKey = "IdBausteintyp")]
public TextbausteinTyp TextbausteinTyp
{
    get { return _textbausteinTyp.Entity; }
    set { _textbausteinTyp.Entity = value; }
}
```

Then you have a `TextbausteinTyp` property that gets or sets a `TextbausteinTyp` related to the foreign key. (Note, you don't have to do this if you want to just explicitly join as necessary in your queries).

Likewise, to the `TextbausteinTyp` class you could choose to add:

```
private EntitySet<Textbaustein> _textbausteins;
[Association(Storage = "_textbausteins", OtherKey = "IdBausteintyp")]
public EntitySet<Textbaustein> Textbausteins
{
    get { return _textbausteins; }
    set { _textbausteins.Assign(value); }
}
```

So as to have the other side of this mapped; the collection of `Textbaustein` entities that are related to that particular `TextbausteinTyp`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is trying to tell you that LinqToSQL is not able to determine what SQL Server type is should store objects of type `TextbausteinTyp`.

LINQ to SQL doesn't support user-defined types - only primitive types. It matches the CLR types with a particular SQL Server type as defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

That said, I can infer that you are trying to define an association between `Textbaustein` and `TextbausteinTyp`. You can use the AssociationAttribute to do this. Below is a modified code sample on how to do this. You might need to reverse the association.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace LinqConsoleApp
{
    public class SqlData : DataContext
    {
        public Table<TextbausteinTyp> TextbausteinTypen;
        public Table<Textbaustein> Textbausteins;

        public SqlData(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
    }

    [Table(Name = "tqTextbausteinTyp")]
    public class TextbausteinTyp
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, DbType = "BigInt IDENTITY NOT NULL", IsDbGenerated = true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
        public int Id;

        [Column]
        public string Name;
    }

    [Table(Name = "tqTextbaustein")]
    public class Textbaustein
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, DbType = "BigInt IDENTITY NOT NULL", IsDbGenerated = true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
        public int Id;

        private EntityRef<TextbausteinTyp> _TextbausteinTyp;

        [Association(Storage = "_TextbausteinTyp", ThisKey = "Id")]
        public TextbausteinTyp IdBausteintyp;

        [Column]
        public string Inhalt;

        [Column]
        public string Name;
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder["Data Source"] = "<SERVERNAME>"
            builder["integrated Security"] = true;
            builder["Initial Catalog"] = "<DATABASE>";

            SqlData db = new SqlData(builder.ConnectionString);

            db.CreateDatabase();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```